# How Do You Get the Name For A Specific Value In A Powershell Hash Table?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

If I have a hash table like..

```
$theHash = @{"dog"="mean"; "cat"="nice";"bird"="annoying"}
```

I can get the key for a value by doing:

```
$theHash."dog"
```

How do I do the reverse? I want to put in something like, "mean" and get "dog" as the output? So if I only know "mean", how do I get dog from that?

Comment: `$theHash.GetEnumerator() | ? Value -eq mean | % Key`

Comment: that worked... cool. what is the | % thing before key? And you don't need to put "mean" in parenthesis? interesting...

Comment: you only have to put it in braces if you're using the $psitem variable like this: $theHash.GetEnumerator() | where-object {$_.Value -eq 'mean'} | foreach-object {$_.Key}

Comment: Note that hashtables are optimized for looking up a value given a key. Going in the reverse direction will be much slower as the size of the hash table gets bigger. If you have a big hash table, and will be doing a lot of reverse look ups, you might want to consider keeping two hash tables, a normal one, and one with the keys and values inverted. Also note that there's no guarantee that a reverse lookup will produce a single value - in your example you could have `@{dog='animal';cat='animal';bird='animal'}`. Specifying 'animal' as the value would return all keys.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$theHash.keys | Where-Object {$theHash["$_"] -eq 'mean'}
```

Comment: that works too. the other guy answered first, but only left a comment, so thanks for the help as well!